# C# Get Administrator Rights For A Single Method

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, admin

I have a Method/Event `Form1_Load` and i want to give it `Administrator Rights`

Because in that Method/Event i associate my program with my extension , Also don't want to start application as administrator , If i do that program will not work correcly

So i have a code :

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

But not works And my application gives error :

> UnauthorizedAccessException

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Your code is demanding that the user is an administrator, but I don't think that what you meant is it?  You want to elevate the user privileges?  Is this Win Forms?

Comment: Yes ,want admin rights for doing associate and this is WinForms

Comment: I'd suggest you read and absorb [What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) by Raymond Chen before you go too far down this route.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, which should be closer to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You won't like this answer, but you can't elevate the user for one method, instead you need to request elevation for the entire application, when it loads.

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for how to do that.

This is also helpful https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3

EDIT:

If you have one task to do, like associating an extension, then you can write the logic for that in a separate EXE that only does that task.  Then you can launch that EXE from your main program with

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("<path to exe>");
```

Provided you have followed the advice in the link above, your EXE will run and request elevation, and should be able to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

"associate my program with my extension": your design is wrong. That association is done when your program gets installed. And there it is no problem at all: the installer is running elevated.

Comment: My program have no install , is external